# pt cruiser 2.2 crd 2003 coolant bleeding

Tags: coolant, chrysler, bleeding, pt-cruiser

Does anybody know if its necessary to bleed air from cooling system after thermostat replacement in this car ? If so does anyone know a correct procedure to do so ?

Answer (score 1):

All cooling systems need to be bled of air when they are filled.

On your vehicle, there is a bleed valve just below the thermostat housing.

[image]

This needs to be open as you fill the cooling system to allow air to escape. Once coolant begins to flow through the bleed valve, close it and top off the system from the overflow tank.

In the event you get some erratic temperature readings or no heat, you may need to reopen this to allow any residual air to escape.

**WARNING:** Do not open hot cooling systems as is can result in injury.